# Is it possible to have a SQL view which doesn't take into account the security policy?

Tags: sql, security, azure-sql-database, security-policy

[Azure SQL]
I have a table1 and a security policy with filter predicate (users see only their own rows).

Can there be a view1 which will summarize all the table1 info by all the users?
I can apply a different security policy on the view for a different audience.

[Here is an outline of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l10sJ.png)

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: Azure SQL, sorry I should mention that